# RANKX does not give the correct result

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a measure (not column)  that would rank users based on value.

Here I am trying to use RANKX function:

```
ranking = 
RANKX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(dim_User, 
            dim_User[UserID],
            dim_User[FirstName]
        ),
        "Ttl Trans", [Ttl Transactions]
)
, [Ttl Transactions]
)
```

[image]

Same result using:

```
rating2 = 
RANKX(
    SUMMARIZE(dim_User,
    dim_User[FirstName]
), [Ttl Transactions]
)
```

Tried this way:

```
rating1 = 
RANKX(
    SUMMARIZE(dim_User,
    dim_User[FirstName],
    "Trans",[Ttl Transactions]
), [Trans]
)
```

But gives me an error:

`The value for 'Trans' cannot be determined. Either the column doesn't exist, or there is no current row for this column.`

I also tried using COUNTROWS() function, but also no success.

It seems like it works if I use a table, not a table expression.
What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**
Adding `ALL(dim_User)` still giving me 1

```
ranking = 
RANKX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(ALL(dim_User), 
            dim_User[UserID],
            dim_User[FirstName]
        ),
        "Ttl Trans", [Ttl Transactions]
)
, [Ttl Transactions]
)
```

---

**UPDATE**

No matter what user I select, in a `rating` in a card is always 1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a measure, it is evaluated within its local filter context. In particular, `dim_User` is filtered by `FirstName` within your measure and is, therefore, ranking `Ttl Trans` only compared to other users with the same `FirstName`.

Since you are ranking based on user, you want to remove the filter context introduced by the visual in order to get the ranking you expect. I'd suggest replacing the table argument `dim_User` with `ALL(dim_User)` to remove all filtering on that table or -- more likely the option you want -- with `ALLSELECTED(dim_User)` to remove the local filter context introduced by the visual while maintaining any filter context from slicers or page-level filters.

---

For your card, you'll need to simulate the filter context that exists in the table:

```
UserRanking =
VAR SelectedUser = SELECTEDVALUE ( dim_User[Name_FirstLast] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        RANKX ( ALL ( dim_User ), [Ttl Transactions] ),
        dim_User[Name_FirstLast] = SelectedUser
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tried that as well. Sorry I should have mention that too. But it still gives me 1

Comment: Even for `RANKX(ALLSELECTED(dim_User), [Ttl Transactions])`?

Comment: Oh, I recreated a table and it works.  So is any way to capture ranking in a card? as a digit when selecting a user? Thanks

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would be different in a card than a table if you just have a single user selected (though you probably want `ALL` not `ALLSELECTED` in that case).

Comment: no matter what user I selected the ranking is 1 if I use card visual.

Comment: Using `RANX(ALL(dim_User), [Ttl Transactions])`?

Comment: yes. If measure used in a table along with userID it works fine, but if I use same measure in a card, no matter what user selected its ranking is 1. Probably because there are no other values to compare with?  I updated question with example.

Comment: Oh! Got it! Thank you very much!